# Where to report a threatening message in an edit summary?

Tags: support, offensive, edit-summary

How and where can I report if a user uses threatening language or bad language in an edit summary message?

Recently, on one of my answers, a user suggested an edit (which was not a valid edit) and in the edit summary they wrote: "*dont mess with me*".

Should I report this? If yes, where?

Reference image:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11666731 <- the edit. (Someone actually voted to approve...)

Comment: Flag using a custom flag for Moderator attention and describe the issue.

Comment: @Mat: Of course. Someone has to be that guy, otherwise all would not be right with the world.

Answer (score 15):

It appears that this user got mad because you edited one of his answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36003300/revisions)).

As stated by [Infinite Recursion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2982225/infinite-recursion), custom flag it, move on and the moderators will handle it.

Comment: Note: Both users have left the building (*"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "don't mess with me" as particularly threatening. It could equally be said as a "warning", or in the tone of annoyance or irk. In such a case, I'd just direct such a user in the comments to /help/editing, and perhaps inline a quote into that comment.

For your copy-pasta purposes: `Concerning your edit summary, please see [/help/editing](/help/editing), which states: "_Editing is important for keeping posts clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you._"`

---

If you actually get a threat of harm or some other retaliative action in an edit summary, then you can take your pick of what to do next depending on how much threat you think there is.

- If it's a petty threat like vandalizing your posts in retaliation, or serial voting, then raise a custom mod flag on the post and explain the situation, asking the mods to take appropriate action. (if threat-maker hasn't actually done anything bad yet, I'm not sure if the mods can actually do anything. at least they can be aware of the potential for abuse of the system though)
- If a threat has been made to your safety or the safety of others, then consider contacting the company, which you can do using [the Contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), and selecting the "Trust and Safety" option, and then the "I want to report a Code of Conduct violation" sub-option. See also [the Code of Conduct page](/conduct).

See also the related Help Center page: [What if I see someone doing something bad?](/help/flagging), which pretty much says the same thing.